# Gmail showing br tag instead of line break

Tags: google-apps-script

Developing Google Add-on using apps script that uses sidebar form to create Gmail draft and then send it.  BR tags from form correctly create line break in Gmail draft, but in Gmail inbox the br tag is showing and there is no line break.  How can I fix this?  Is there a working code sample you could share?

See image in google drive.
[Drafts and Inbox](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pLkSSmOR20MEFxcE5XOHZHWUU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Since no code was posted, I assume that you are using the MailApp.sendEmail() function.

If so, then by default, it only sends plain text email and not HTML email. Which is why you see the BR tag.

To send HTML email, you have to use the parameter htmlBody

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Good luck!

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!